# Short Exact Sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $M \ge N \ge P$ be R-modules. Prove that there exist natural (not depending on choices) R-homomorphisms $N/P \to M/P$ and  $M/P \to M/N$ for which the sequence $0 \to N/P \to M/P \to M/N \to 0$ is exact.

I am having difficulty with just about everything to prove this--even what exactly it is asking. I would be assuming that the sequence given is exact and then proving that $N/P \to M/P$ and  $M/P \to M/N$ are homomorphisms?

How does one go about "not making choices"?

Also, could you give me a hint on how to prove this? If I assume that it is exact, then I would have the $f: N/P \to M/P$ is injective, and $g:M/P \to M/N$ is surjective.

Comment: I think "not making choices" just means that the maps are well-defined; regardless of which "choice" of coset representative you choose, the map takes it to the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint;

Define the map $f: N/P \to M/P$ to be $f(n+P)=n+P$ this is an injective $R-$ module homomorphism, and the map $g: M/P \to M/N$ to be $g(m+P)=m+N$ this is a surjective $R-$ module homomorphism.

Or;

From $N/P\le M/P$ we get the following exact sequence 
$$0\to N/P \to M/P \to (M/P)/(N/P)\simeq M/N\to0$$

Comment: By defining a map, aren't I "making choices"?

Comment: I used the word define to give you the explicit maps that you want, otherwise the map $f$ is just an extension for the inclusion, and $g$ is the projection.

Comment: Ok. So assuming the sequence is exact, then $im(f)=ker(g)$, with f,g R-modular homomorphisms. Thus, f must be injective, which occurs iff $ker (f)$ = $\{\}$, and g must be surjective, which occurs iff $im (g) =M/N$. Thus, the map f must be an extension, and g must be a projection. Is that it?

Comment: In this case they are injection and surjection. Note that $kerf=0$ not the empty set, and I said the extension of the inclusion not the extension alone.